# How do I get an anonymous user object from SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, wss, sharepoint-2010, fba

I have a site setup using Claims Based (Forms) authentication with Anonymous access enabled.

When a user logs into the site they may exist in the Forms Database, but not in the SharePoint Site collection. In this case SPContext.Current.Web.SPUser returns NULL - even though they are logged in.

Is there another object similar to SPUser that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true? If so, try putting a call to SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) before digging into Web.CurrentUser (which is what I presume you meant, not Web.SPUser)

-Oisin

Comment: that might be Web.User too (can't remember)

Comment: This, is - in fact, what I ended up doing. =)
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null)
{
  IIDentity myIdent = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;  
  // Do some more identity stuff
}